# Lazy Loading BrowserModule has already been loaded while importing NgClockPickerLibModule in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-lazyloading

Importing NgClockPickerLib Module in Lazy loaded module which is creating error :
`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.`

This is because NgClockPickerLib Module  internally imports BrowserAnimations Module.

How to use NgClockPickerLib Module  in lazy loaded module ??

**app module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SharedDataService } from './services/shared-data.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,  
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    SharedDataService,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**app routing module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'journalling', loadChildren: './Journalling/modules/journalling.module#JournallingModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [

  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**journalling module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { JournallingRoutingModule } from './journalling-routing.module';
import { NgClockPickerLibModule } from 'ng-clock-picker-lib';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    JournallingRoutingModule,
    NgClockPickerLibModule
  ],
  declarations: [ 
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class JournallingModule { }
```

[image]

Comment: looks like a NgClockPickerLibModule bug. authour shouldn't be importing BrowserModule as well as BrowserAnimationsModule

Comment: so whats the solution ? How can i use the NgClockPickerLibModule in lazy loaded module ?

Comment: can it be done like importing NgClockPickerLibModule in AppModule and exporting it and making it accessible to JournallingModule ?

Comment: Or can we eagerly load the JournallingModule (it contains only 2 components and few 3rd party modules) . will this solve the problem and how to eagerly load a module ?